# sudo command not working in vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

Im using vagrant. I don't even know why but for some reason I recursively ran chmod 777 in /usr/. Now whenever i try to run anything with sudo I get the following error:

> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

I'm using vagrant for this.

Does anyone have any idea on how to change this permission back to the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recursively ran chmod 777 in /usr

well I see 2 options :

## vagrant destroy

backup what you need to save and rebuild the VM (`vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`) This is an advantage of vagrant if you can quickly rebuild your environment from provisioning and if you work with sync folder to have everything saved from your host.

## trying to fix

you would need to login as root and fix a few things

1. start your VM either from VirtualBox or `vagrant up`
2. go to Virtual Box and login as `root` (password should be `vagrant`) (hopefully you can login at this stage, else will be more complicated)
3. change back things -

   ```
   chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
   ```

That will fix `sudo` but as you recursively changed all files under the folder, you would need to fix each ones; everything should be owned by `root` there so you could run `chown -R` on the folder and most of the permissions are `755` but not all so you could try running `chmod -R 755 /usr` (leaving the sticky bit) but I do not guarantee it would work

4. log off from virtual box, try to run `vagrant ssh`

Comment: Tried option 2 first, didnt rlly work option 1 is fine, Thanks!

Comment: if you had change sudo only it would be ok but the whole `/usr` folder, well its a bit too much !